# Check "input type" if value is empty then insert default text

Tags: mysql, html, forms, user-input, default-value

I'm not very advanced so it takes me a long time to get anywhere but I persist and so far have gotten this to work:

```
<input 
 type="text"
 name="product_desc[<?php echo $language['language_id']; ?>][tab_extra]"
 size ="50"
 value="<?php echo isset($product_desc[$language['language_id']]) ?
       $product_desc[$language['language_id']]['tab_extra'] : ''; ?>"
/>
```

It looks to the database and displays the value, but allows me to update, delete or change the text that is contained there. Great, except most of the time I need that tab to be called 'Extra' and only rarely will I ever need to change the title. I was thinking of using placeholder but that doesn't really do what I need it to do.

I'm thinking an IF...ELSE statement could work, something like IF tab_extra is empty than display the word 'Extra' by default in the input box. My searches always come up empty because of all the "how do I clear the default value on click" questions that exist, and that's not what I want to do at all.

So to wrap up...look at the database and if the field is empty, add the word 'Extra' to be inserted into the database.

Comment: I don't understand why 3 people think my question isn't valid. To some folks it's easy then when you have a full time job and can only learn coding a few hours a week and spend 3 hours researching it then come here for help and not deemed "good enough" where should I go then?

Comment: I'm not sure why you've been downvoted (I am certainly **not** one of them). You are in the right place, the anonymous downvoters are IMHO in the wrong place. Good luck with your project

Answer (score 0):

When selecting from a MySQL database, if you have a table like

```
table baz:

foo         bar
=========   =========
value1      NULL
value2      Optional
value3      NULL
```

and want to retrieve the word "Extra" wherever the "bar" column is NULL, then you can use the `coalesce` function

```
select coalesce(bar, 'Extra') as bar from baz;
```